# Fixed navbar hiding header

Tags: html, css

Whenever I set my navbar to fixed and my header height is 100vh, my header seems to be under the navbar. How can I make the navbar not cover my header and make header 100vh

```css
.nav {
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}


.hero {
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

</div>

<div class="hero">

</div>
```

Comment: try `body { scroll-margin-top: 80px; }`

Comment: @Spectric I do not want part of my header to be hidden under navbar.

Comment: height:calc(100vh - 80px) to hero ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: sticky` instead of `position: fixed`. This way your main container will always be `100vh`.

In css I made edits.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  height: 80px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /*left: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}


.hero {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /*margin-top: 80px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

</div>

<div class="hero">

</div>
```

Comment: Is the sticky best solution for this? I've seen many sites using fixed property.

Comment: @Dave, Yes, it does, but only if `.nav` is outside of the content container. I myself always only use sticky position in my projects for the top menu.

Comment: But when I use ur solution, and set header to 100vh, i still can scroll down for some reason. Idk why

Comment: @Dave, Why are you setting header to 100vh? The code you showed works with `position: sticky`. Show the complete structure of the html. I will help you.

Comment: I just want the header to fill the remaining space on screen.

Comment: Because header size looks like 100vh+ 80px now and there is 80px to scroll at bottom

Comment: @Dave, Do you want something like calc(100vh - 80px) for `.hero`?

Comment: Yeah, but is this proper approach? will this not crash on responsive? Usually I dont set height of my navbar, I just use padding inside.

Comment: @Dave, It doesn't make sense. if you are `.hero` will contain a lot of content.

Comment: @Dave, and I forgot to tell you .. Replace `height` with `min-height` at `.hero`. This will provide height when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the nav to `position:sticky;` instead

example: https://jsfiddle.net/sq5ae3u1/

Comment: You forgot to plug in the `top` rule for the sticky container.

Comment: You forgot to answer AFTER me

Comment: always use a SO code snippet as example. If the fiddle link changes or you would chaneg the content, then this anwser would be of no further use to the community.